# LEFT JOIN DUPLICATING VALUES (QUERY WITH WHERE IN)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get rid of duplicated values return from a LEFT JOIN that I did, I'm such a beginner in SQL so I do hope you guys help me out!

```
SELECT *
    ,tm.TEAM_NAME
    ,up.USER_NAME OWNER_NAME
    FROM NTTUS_INIT_TM_TASK_HEADER th
    LEFT JOIN NTTUS_TEAM tm
    ON th.TEAM_ID = tm.TEAM_ID
    LEFT JOIN NTTUS_USER_PROFILE up
    ON th.OWNER_ID = up.USER_ID
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND INIT_ID IN(${arr.ids})
```

Comment: you need to show us some sample data from each of that table and the expected result. Please do not post as image, use text

Comment: Have you looked at DISTINCT? Also the code snippet you posted has a certain code smell to it. It looks like your likely not parameterizing your queries which can lead to sql injection.

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to do with your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Actually from your description, it's hard to understand your table. But try this. If this doesn't work let me know

```
 SELECT *
    ,tm.TEAM_NAME
    ,up.USER_NAME OWNER_NAME
FROM 
     NTTUS_INIT_TM_TASK_HEADER as th
LEFT JOIN 
     NTTUS_TEAM as tm  ON th.TEAM_ID = tm.TEAM_ID
LEFT JOIN 
     NTTUS_USER_PROFILE as up ON th.OWNER_ID = up.USER_ID
WHERE 
    INIT_ID IN(${arr.ids})
Group By 
     th.*
    ,tm.TEAM_NAME
    ,up.USER_NAME OWNER_NAME
Having count(*) = 1
```